Does the Tableau Meta-Data API provide a way to programmatically attach attributes to content?
The Tableau metadata API documentation mentions that you can associate tags with content on the server, but is there a way to associate additional custom info with content via the graph QL API?
More specifically, is there a way to associate a text string with a key with workbooks and store that info on the server? Say a key/value pair for each workbook, for example “Approver” = “Fred” or “Legal Info” = “some long XML or JSON string”. I wouldn’t necessarily want to display this info, just have it accessible via an API like the meta-data API.
I’m aware of the Postgres Repository - would prefer not to connect to it directly if there is an existing API available.

I looked into this, other than adding tags via the REST API through datasource update methods and then grabbing them via the graph QL API, I couldn't really find/ solve what you were looking for. Although not ideal as tags can be edited pretty liberally.

Thanks. I kind of hit a dead end there also. Custom attributes Seems like an obvious feature to add if you’re going to maintain a catalo
